# Finding twin primes between two values

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I've been stuck on this problem for ages now and don't seem to know how to complete this program. I am a beginner in programming so I only know C. I will admit this is for an assignment and I am not looking for the answer but I would really appreciate a little help with the problem. This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int low, high, n, count,i;

    scanf ("%d %d",&low, &high);

    count=0;
    n=0;

    if (low<=3)
        count=count+1;


    while (n<low)
        {
        n=n+6;  
        }

    while (n<high)
    {
     i=1;

       while (i<sqrt(n+1))
        {
        i=i+2;

        if ((n-1)%i==0 || (n+1)%i==0)

        continue;

            else
                count=count+1;
        }

        n=n+6;

    }

 printf("the number of twin primes between %d and %d are %d",low, high, count);
 }
```

Am I using `while` loops wrong and/or the `if` statements? I haven't been taught to use for loops so I can't use those. I also have to use the fact that every twin prime besides `{3,5}` follow the formula 6+/-1.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please edit and fix your formatting.

Comment: What exactly is your problem -- program crashing, program not giving correct results?  Also, the format string to the scanf looks 'fishy' -- I think you may have forgotten a space between the two conversion specifiers (the `%d`'s)

Comment: It's a good time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: It's not giving me correct results, for example if I put in a range of 1 to 100, the result should be 8 because there are 8 twin primes in that given range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int low, high, n, count, i;

    scanf ("%d %d", &low, &high);

    count = 0;
    n = 0;

    if (low <= 3)
        count++;


    while (n<low)
        n += 6;

    while (n < high) {
        i = 1;
        int flag = 0;

        while (i * i < n + 1) {
            i++;
            if ((n - 1) % i == 0 || (n + 1) % i == 0)
                flag = 1;
        }
        if (!flag)
            count++;
        n += 6;
    }
    printf("the number of twin primes between %d and %d are %d", low, high, count);
}
```

as you can see you need just something like flag for your prime detection phase.

Comment: That's amazing thank you! I just don't understand the purpose of the flag, could you explain please?

Comment: A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has *no positive divisors* other than 1 and itself, so you must decide when you check all of it's divisors but you decide when you check one of it's divisors. sorry for my bad English

Comment: The first loop in this answer (and in the question) is `while (n<low) n += 6;` which is a slow way of writing `n = low / 6;`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not want to change his code so much.